# Update all content types inheriting from this type?

Tags: 2010

I've added a column to a content type view of a list, and while changing the column order SharePoint asks this:

> **Update Sites and Lists**
>
> Specify whether all child site and list content types using this type
>   should be updated with the settings on this page. **This operation can
>   take a long time, and any customizations made to the child site and
>   list content types will be lost.**
>
> Update all content types inheriting from this type?

That sounds dangerous to me; is there a way to view and/or backup&restore  all child site and list content types using this type?

Comment: Why don't you take backup of whole site collection before doing it ? :)

Comment: I don't see the subdomain i'm using in the backup options of the Central Admin. Using the default i got a 206 MB backup file. Kinda excessive for just a column order change. Also, i've already added and ordered the column (with inheritance) without apparent breakage, but the other columns have a different Source...

Comment: The content type source lacked the column i added, so i ordered a different column and inherited that. Now the first column i added to all children disappeared and the parent column only appears in the view but not the column edit screens of the child content types. :(

Comment: The site now shows "Travelers" (added to child content types) near the bottom instead of the top, but the columns edit screen only shows "Travellers" (added to parent content type).

Comment: I've deleted the Travelers column in List Settings, and then was able to add and order the new Travellers column in the first child content type. The List columns overview is lacking clear parentage as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think `/_layouts/ListEdit.aspx` shows every child content type that will be affected if a given column is altered, and `/_admin/SiteAndListExport.aspx` in Central Administration the smallest & fastest way to backup and restore affected lists.

Though in my case, i can't find the list on the backup page.